# Linux: ¿Por que hay iconos unicode que funcionan y otros no?

Tags: linux, ascii, unicode, icono

estoy intentando generar iconos unicodes, los mas simples. Desde la terminal de linux.

Este caso funciona (icono de un tick de aprobado):

```
echo -e "\u2705"
```

Este otro caso no funciona (icono disquete):

```
echo -e "\u1F4BE"
```

He mirado el icono del disquete en varios sitios, este es uno de ellos:
https://unicode-table.com/es/1F4BE/

Comment: Pruébalo en mayúsculas:  echo -e "\U1F4BE".  Es lo que ponen en la web que tu mismo has referenciado y a mi me funciona en mi terminal, en cambio, con la `u` minúscula no.

Comment: Tal vez la tipografía del terminal no posee un glifo para ese carácter.

Comment: @masterguru Esto era. Daba por hecho que todas iban a ser con `u` minuscula

Comment: Cierto! Funciona si pones el valor hex en mayúsculas. Probado en Linux Mint